# Possible to build a source.changes file from a deb package?

Tags: dpkg, compiling, packaging

I want to build a source.changes file to publish a package. But I have no idea how to build it. I created a .deb file containing the source code and the compiled binary. Is there any way to convert it or something like that ? Or Am I completely wrong ?

Comment: How did you make the .deb?

Comment: With dpkg-deb --build

Comment: `debuild -S -sa`